# finding and moving all cells that are in 1 column that have same prefix - google sheet - google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first coding project. Been just teaching myself, and am pretty stuck.

I have a column of data in a Google Spreadsheet. It is sorted alphabetically. I need a script that will search the data for any cells that start with the same 8 characters and will move those to a new column.

The code needs to do something like this: "start at row 1 in column A, get first 8 characters from that cell, if any other cells match those first 8 characters (*note the column is already sorted alphabetically, so they should all be next to each other), move those cells to column B", then loop (i.e. start at next row with data, look at first 8 characters in that cell, if any other cells match those first 8 characters, then move those cells to column C".

Here is a representation of the data I have.

|  |
| --- |
| Blacklist - S02E01 |
| Blacklist - S02E02 |
| Blacklist - S02E02 - 2 |
| Breaking Bad - S01E05 |
| Firefly - S01E01 |
| Firefly - S01E02 |
| Firefly - S01E03 |
| Firefly - S01E04 |
| Firefly - S01E05 |
| Three Billboards - 1 |
| Three Billboards - 2 |
| Three Billboards - 3 |

I want to end up with this:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Blacklist - S02E01 | Breaking Bad - S01E05 | Firefly - S01E01 | Three Billboards - 1 |
|  | Blacklist - S02E02 |  | Firefly - S01E02 | Three Billboards - 2 |
|  | Blacklist - S02E02 - 2 |  | Firefly - S01E03 | Three Billboards - 3 |
|  |  |  | Firefly - S01E04 |  |
|  |  |  | Firefly - S01E05 |  |

I think the best way to accomplish this is to use either TextFinder or getValues in a loop to get a range of all cells that start with the same prefix and then us moveTo. This would all need to be done in a loop, but I am not very good with loops and can't put it all together.

I tried this, but I am sure there are multiple problems here:

```html
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
let sss = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
let val1 = sss.getRange(8,4).getValue()
let sval1 = val1.substring(0,8)
var rows = sss.getRange('D8:D500');
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[0].length > 1 && row[0].substr(0, 8) == sval1)
sss.getRange(row).moveTo(sheet.getRange("E8"));
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is it always 5 letters?

Comment: It actually varies, but I think the first 8 characters would generally work. A better representation of the data is something like this...

ABC123DEF456randomletters1
ABC123DEF456randomletters2
CRTD322DLOrandomletters1
CRTD322DLOrandomletters2
HYTRM45678randomletters1
HYTRM45678randomletters2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function distribute() {
  const sA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];//map first letters to columns
  let col = {};
  sA.forEach((l, i) => { col[l] = i + 1 });
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow());
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues().flat();
  rg.clearContent();
  let sObj = {pA:[]};
  let oA = vs.map(e => {
    let l = e.slice(0,1);//take one letter
    if(!sObj.hasOwnProperty(col[l])) {
      sObj[col[l]] = [];
      sObj[col[l]].push([e]);
      sObj.pA.push(col[l]);
    } else {
      sObj[col[l]].push([e]);
    }
  });
  sObj.pA.forEach(c => {
    sh.getRange(1,c,sObj[c].length).setValues(sObj[c]);
  }); 
}
```

Before:

| A |
| --- |
| AAAAA123 |
| BBBBB100 |
| BBBBB123 |
| BBBBB232 |
| BBBBB256 |
| CCCCC123 |
| CCCCC278 |
| DDDDD322 |
| DDDDD458 |
| DDDDD788 |

After:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA123 | BBBBB100 | CCCCC123 | DDDDD322 |
|  | BBBBB123 | CCCCC278 | DDDDD458 |
|  | BBBBB232 |  | DDDDD788 |
|  | BBBBB256 |  |  |

You could also do it this way:

```
function distribute() {
  const sA = ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'EEEEE'];//map prefixes to columns
  let col = {};
  sA.forEach((l, i) => { col[l] = i + 1 });
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow());
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues().flat();
  rg.clearContent();
  let sObj = {pA:[]};
  let oA = vs.map(e => {
    //this is the same kind of structure as a reverse pivot table
    let l = e.slice(0,5);//take 5 letters
    if(!sObj.hasOwnProperty(col[l])) {
      sObj[col[l]] = [];
      sObj[col[l]].push([e]);
      sObj.pA.push(col[l]);
    } else {
      sObj[col[l]].push([e]);
    }
  });
  sObj.pA.forEach(c => {
    sh.getRange(1,c,sObj[c].length).setValues(sObj[c]);
  }); 
}
```

Yet another way:

Code:

```
function distribute() {
  const sc = 2;
  const sr = 2
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1);
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues().flat();
  //rg.clearContent();
  let col = { pA: [] };
  let sObj = { pA: [] };
  let oA = vs.map(e => {
    let l = e.slice(0, 8);
    if (!col.hasOwnProperty(l)) {
      col[l] = col.pA.length + sc;
      col.pA.push(l);
    }
    if (!sObj.hasOwnProperty(col[l])) {
      sObj[col[l]] = [];
      sObj[col[l]].push([e]);
      sObj.pA.push(col[l]);
    } else {
      sObj[col[l]].push([e]);
    }
  });
  sObj.pA.forEach(c => {
    sh.getRange(sr, c, sObj[c].length).setValues(sObj[c]);
  });
}
```

Sheet0 before:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blacklist - S02E01 |  |  |  |  |
| Blacklist - S02E02 |  |  |  |  |
| Blacklist - S02E02 - 2 |  |  |  |  |
| Breaking Bad - S01E05 |  |  |  |  |
| Firefly - S01E01 |  |  |  |  |
| Firefly - S01E02 |  |  |  |  |
| Firefly - S01E03 |  |  |  |  |
| Firefly - S01E04 |  |  |  |  |
| Firefly - S01E05 |  |  |  |  |
| Three Billboards - 1 |  |  |  |  |
| Three Billboards - 2 |  |  |  |  |
| Three Billboards - 3 |  |  |  |  |

Sheet0 After:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blacklist - S02E01 | Blacklist - S02E01 | Breaking Bad - S01E05 | Firefly - S01E01 | Three Billboards - 1 |
| Blacklist - S02E02 | Blacklist - S02E02 |  | Firefly - S01E02 | Three Billboards - 2 |
| Blacklist - S02E02 - 2 | Blacklist - S02E02 - 2 |  | Firefly - S01E03 | Three Billboards - 3 |
| Breaking Bad - S01E05 |  |  | Firefly - S01E04 |  |
| Firefly - S01E01 |  |  | Firefly - S01E05 |  |
| Firefly - S01E02 |  |  |  |  |
| Firefly - S01E03 |  |  |  |  |
| Firefly - S01E04 |  |  |  |  |
| Firefly - S01E05 |  |  |  |  |
| Three Billboards - 1 |  |  |  |  |
| Three Billboards - 2 |  |  |  |  |
| Three Billboards - 3 |  |  |  |  |

remove the comment on the rg.clearContent() line and you get this:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Blacklist - S02E01 | Breaking Bad - S01E05 | Firefly - S01E01 | Three Billboards - 1 |
|  | Blacklist - S02E02 |  | Firefly - S01E02 | Three Billboards - 2 |
|  | Blacklist - S02E02 - 2 |  | Firefly - S01E03 | Three Billboards - 3 |
|  |  |  | Firefly - S01E04 |  |
|  |  |  | Firefly - S01E05 |  |

Comment: I think I have a ton I can learn from your answers. Nobody told me about that `.flat()` method!! I'm not a natural JS coder (VBA in case you didn't see my overenthusiastically deleted answer). There's a lot in here that's really useful. Thanks!!

Comment: @Cooper - Thanks so much! But what if the prefix can't be hard-coded? Is there a way to say "start at row 1 in column A, get first 8 characters from that cell, if any other cells match those first 8 characters (*note the column is already sorted, so they should all be next to each other), move those cells to column B", then loop (i.e. start at next row with data, look at first 8 cells, if any other cells match those first 8 characters, then move those cells to column C". Does that make sense?

Comment: I would need to know more details of your specific need but I could imagine a solution where x is a variable in `let l = e.slice(0,x);`  But you still need to provide a way to make the prefixes to columns

Comment: Ask another question like that and provide input data and required output and see what you get.

Comment: So I think the question you're asking is how can I solve the problem without knowing what sA is until I scan all of the data to figure out what the unique prefixes are.  Then the question I'd ask is, how do I assign the prefixes to columns without some a priori knowledge like alphabetical order or an example given in the question.

Comment: @cooper - I updated the question with a lot more detail. Thanks for your patience. This is my first time posting.

Comment: @joeleeway99, yeah but he already answered your originally posted question. Changing (or clarifying) your question after receiving an answer that addressed an original question, without `accepting` the answer, is rather frowned upon on StackOverflow.

Comment: @pgSystemTester - Got it. Thanks so much (again, I am very new here). I will accept the answer from cooper. Should I create a new question then with the additional detail?

Comment: Okay that turned out to be a pretty easy change.  I didn't delete the first column but that's an easy thing to do.

Comment: @cooper. That worked great, except a few other questions. 1) These values are actually hyperlinks and that is getting lost on paste. Any ideas on how to fix? 2) Any way to make the matches case insensitive? 3) Just for my education. I am really trying to understand how a developer chooses to solve a problem a certain way. I see you are using a lot of array based functions, which is totally different from my idea of using substr() and moveTo(). Do you think my approach could work? Why is yours "better" (other than the fact that yours works, and my idea was only half-finished).

Comment: There's probably a way to fix the hyperlinks.  May be with richText. `let l = e.slice(0, 8).toLowerCase();` The less code you write the less code you have to debug.

Comment: @Cooper - So the script is working great, but I still can't quite figure out how to get the full URL. I created a flat array of the full formulas in the range, but I can't figure out how to use that for setting the values at the end. Any ideas? I can understand about 60% of your code, but I have never worked with Arrays with keys before and am not sure what code like  `col[first8charactersarray]` and `sObj[col[first8charactersarray]]` is doing