# finding and moving all cells that are in 1 column that start with the same characters - google sheet - google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is my first coding project. Been just teaching myself, and am pretty stuck.

I asked this question previously - [finding and moving all cells that are in 1 column that have same prefix - google sheet - google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749161/finding-and-moving-all-cells-that-are-in-1-column-that-have-same-prefix-google) - (with less detail) and got a great answer, but still need some help

I have a column of data in a Google Spreadsheet. It is sorted alphabetically. I need a script that will search the data for any cells that start with the same 8 characters and will move those to a new column.

The data in the column are all hyperlink formulas, like =hyperlink("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3381714/ , "Blacklist - S02E01"), and I want to keep all of that data (hyperlink and title)

The code needs to do something like this: "start at row 1 in column A, get first 8 characters from that cell, if any other cells match those first 8 characters (*note the column is already sorted alphabetically, so they should all be next to each other), move those cells to column B", then loop (i.e. start at next row with data, look at first 8 characters in that cell, if any other cells match those first 8 characters, then move those cells to column C".

Here is a representation of the data I have.

|  |
| --- |
| Blacklist - S02E01 |
| Blacklist - S02E02 |
| Blacklist - S02E02 - 2 |
| Breaking Bad - S01E05 |
| Firefly - S01E01 |
| Firefly - S01E02 |
| Firefly - S01E03 |
| Firefly - S01E04 |
| Firefly - S01E05 |
| Three Billboards - 1 |
| Three Billboards - 2 |
| Three Billboards - 3 |

I want to end up with this:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Blacklist - S02E01 | Breaking Bad - S01E05 | Firefly - S01E01 | Three Billboards - 1 |
|  | Blacklist - S02E02 |  | Firefly - S01E02 | Three Billboards - 2 |
|  | Blacklist - S02E02 - 2 |  | Firefly - S01E03 | Three Billboards - 3 |
|  |  |  | Firefly - S01E04 |  |
|  |  |  | Firefly - S01E05 |  |

I think the best way to accomplish this is to use either TextFinder or getValues in a loop to get a range of all cells that start with the same prefix and then us moveTo. This would all need to be done in a loop, but I am not very good with loops and can't put it all together.

I tried this, but I am sure there are multiple problems here:

```html
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
let sss = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
let val1 = sss.getRange(8,4).getValue()
let sval1 = val1.substring(0,8)
var rows = sss.getRange('D8:D500');
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[0].length > 1 && row[0].substr(0, 8) == sval1)
sss.getRange(row).moveTo(sheet.getRange("E8"));
```

The solution from my first question - [finding and moving all cells that are in 1 column that have same prefix - google sheet - google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749161/finding-and-moving-all-cells-that-are-in-1-column-that-have-same-prefix-google) - involved a bunch of array actions. It works great, but it only copies and pastes the display value, but not the full formula that includes hyperlink data.

I tried editing it it make it work, but got stuck and don't understand JavaScript arrays enough to understand that answer completely.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion

You can to use the [getFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula) method to get the full formula *(it'll get the hyperlink and the display value)* of a cell then you can set it to a new cell.

Here's a sample script below for more context. This sample will loop through the column A rows, then it'll compare & sort each row values via the `substring(0,8)` method:

```
function sortItems(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var row = 1; //Start row
  var column = 2; //Start column

  for(x=1; x <= sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length; x++){ //Loop will start on row 1
    var next = x+1; //Used to get the next row value to compare to the current row value
    if(sheet.getRange("A"+x).getValue().substring(0,8) == sheet.getRange("A"+next).getValue().substring(0,8)){
      Logger.log(sheet.getRange("A"+x).getValue() +" is equal to "+ sheet.getRange("A"+next).getValue()); //Log for review
      sheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(sheet.getRange("A"+x).getFormula());
      row++ //Move to the proceeding row
    }else{
      Logger.log(sheet.getRange("A"+x).getValue() +" is NOT equal to "+ sheet.getRange("A"+next).getValue()); //Log for review
      sheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(sheet.getRange("A"+x).getFormula()); //Add last value on the current column
      row = 1; //Reset the row to 1 for the next column
      column++; //Set the next column
      sheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(sheet.getRange("A"+next).getFormula()); //Add the first value on the new column
    }
  }
}
```

***[UPDATE]***

*Script Version 2*

```
function sortItemsVer2(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var row = 1; //Start row
  var column = 2; //Start column
  var rawData = [];
  for(x=1; x <= sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length; x++){ //Get all row data on column A into 'rawData' array variable
    rawData.push([sheet.getRange("A"+x).getValue(),sheet.getRange("A"+x).getFormula()]) ;
  }
  sortRawData(sheet, row, column, rawData);
}

function sortRawData(sheet, row, column, rawData){ //Function to sort 'RawData' array
    for(x=0; x <= rawData.length; x++){ //Loop will start on index 0
    var next = x+1; //Used to get the next row value to compare to the current row value
    try{
      if(rawData[x][0].substring(0,8) == rawData[next][0].substring(0,8)){
      Logger.log(rawData[x][0] +" is equal to "+ rawData[next][0]); //Log for review
      sheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(rawData[x][1]);
      row++ //Move to the proceeding row
    }else{
      Logger.log(rawData[x][0] +" is NOT equal to "+ rawData[next][0]); //Log for review
      sheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(rawData[x][1]); //Add last value on the first column
      row = 1; //Reset the row to 1 for the next column
      column++; //set the next column
      sheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(rawData[next][1]); //Add the first value on the next column
    }
    }catch (e){ //This will add the very last data from column A on the last column
      sheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(rawData[x][1]); 
      row = 1; //Reset the row to 1 for the next column
      column++; //set the next column
      sheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(rawData[next][1]); 
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Result

***Sample Sheet***

> [image]

***The sample sheet after running the script***

> [image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That works great. One more question. This script runs quite a bit slower than the one suggested from my other question. Any ideas how to speed it up? Maybe it isn't possible. Again, I am very new to coding, so I am also trying to understand what generally affects the speed of a script.

Comment: You're welcome. My current code manipulates live sheet data, thus, it runs slower than usual. I have created a version 2 of my script on my answer, where I first placed all column A data into an array variable and then it'll sort the array data in a new function instead of sorting live sheet cells via getValue() inside the loop method. If ever you'll test this, just disregard the error on console log as it is due to the last array value that can't be compared to a next value because it is already the last one. This script works on my end and hopefully it will make the process a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks again. This is working a bit faster. The error I am getting is " 
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
sortRawData @ distv4.gs:32
sortItemsVer2 @ distv4.gs:10" -- is that the error you are suggesting I ignore?

Comment: Yup, that's the error  due to the last array value that can't be compared to a next value because it is already the last one.

Comment: Great. Thanks again!